# Multiple out parameters in SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

In  Java spring boot framework,trying to  consume the Store procedure  using the following method

```
 jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);

       SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                                           .withSchemaName("abc")
                                           .withFunctionName("proname")
                                           .addDeclaredParameter(new
 SqlOutParameter("",""));
        Map<String, Object> map= new HashMap<>();
         map.put("a",a);
        map.put("b",b);
        map.put("c",c);
        map.put("d",d);

 SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(map);
 Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

but my procedure also has out parameters  here is my procedure

```
function proname(z varchar2,
                                            a varchar2,
                                            b varchar2,
                                            c varchar2,
                                            d in out number,
                                            e out number,
                                            f out varchar2,
                                            g out varchar2)
```

the procedure also has out parameters as one can see in above code, Question is how can I mention multiple out parameters(Note Multiple ) in Simple JDBC Call????

Answer (score 1):

I tried like following and it works:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute((CallableStatementCreator) con -> {
        con = con.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{ ? = call usr.abc.proname(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) }");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleType.NUMBER);
        cs.setString(2, "a");
        cs.setString(3, "b");
        cs.setString(4, "c");
        cs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleType.NUMBER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(5, OracleType.NUMBER);
        cs.registerOutParameter(6, OracleType.VARCHAR);
        cs.registerOutParameter(7, OracleType.VARCHAR);
        return cs;
    }, (CallableStatementCallback<MyModel>) cs -> {
        cs.execute();
        return new MyModel(cs.getInt(1),
                           cs.getInt(4),
                           cs.getInt(5),
                           cs.getString(6),
                           cs.getString(7));
    });
```

Comment: the OP asked about SimpleJdbcCall example and not about how to call a function using java.sql.Connection. Also there is no need of unwrapping OracleConnection to do such kind of simple calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following tutorials to accept multiple `out` parameters from a stored procedure. This should give you a brief into how this can be implemented:

1. [Spring JDBC with Stored Procedures](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_stored_procedure.htm)
2. [Spring JDBC with Simple JDBC Call](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_simplejdbccall.htm)

Taking sample code from the above articles, this is how you would be making a call to execute your Stored Procedure:

```
SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("getRecord");
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("in_id", id);
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
```

From the same example, once you get your required output, you would be fetching the `OUT` parameters from the response in this format:

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setId(id);
student.setName((String) out.get("out_name"));
student.setAge((Integer) out.get("out_age"));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a function not a procedure

Comment: The OP is asking about how to call a db function with multiple InOut and Out parameters this answer simply shows how to call a procedure with a single parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleJdbcCall's [declareParameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch12s05.html) method,example:

> ```
> .declareParameters(
>                             new SqlParameter("in_id", Types.NUMERIC),
>                             new SqlOutParameter("out_first_name", Types.VARCHAR),
>                             new SqlOutParameter("out_last_name", Types.VARCHAR),
>                             new SqlOutParameter("out_birth_date", Types.DATE)
>                     );
> ```

Comment: I tried this and got exception: `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1`

Comment: @Ulphat add all input parameters as `SqlParameter` and output parameters as `SqlOutParameter`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
   SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("PRONAME")

                .declareParameters(
                        new SqlParameter("z", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("a", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("b", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlParameter("c", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlInOutParameter("d", Types.NUMERIC),
                        new SqlOutParameter("e", Types.NUMERIC),
                        new SqlOutParameter("f", Types.VARCHAR),
                        new SqlOutParameter("g", Types.VARCHAR)
                );


        Map<String, Object> result = call.execute("z", "a", "b", "c", 7);
        System.out.println(result);
```

result:

`{return=test, d=5, e=6, f=b, g=c}`

and this is the function:

```
create function proname(z varchar2,
                                            a varchar2,
                                            b varchar2,
                                            c varchar2,
                                            d in out number,
                                            e out number,
                                            f out varchar2,
                                            g out varchar2)
                                            return varchar2 is
begin
 d:=5;
 e:=6;
 f:='b';
 g:='c';  

return 'test';
end;
```

Note: in `.declareParameters` parameter order, type and direction must match with the db function's parameters.

Comment: With spring-jdbc-5.2.5 and Oracle 11, the above did not work for me. I needed to add and extra line`call.setAccessCallParameterMetaData(false)` otherwise the SQL is translated as `{ ? = call proname() }` i.e. no parameters use. Also  `new SqlOutParameter("return", Types.VARCHAR)` should be the first param, otherwise I got 'PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call'. *HOWEVER* my function's types were defined as `%TYPE` which may have caused this complication and the need for extra code.

Comment: What about if your stored proc OUT params are user-defined custom types in your oracle db like a "employee_t" or "finances_t" types that have multiple fields? How the hell do you map that to a Java class?  I tried everything and its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [morejdbc](https://github.com/seregamorph/morejdbc) (available in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.seregamorph/morejdbc)), it is convenient and type-safe. Your call will look like:

```java
import static org.morejdbc.SqlTypes.*;
import static org.morejdbc.NamedJdbcCall.call;
import org.morejdbc.*;
...
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
Out<Integer> outD = Out.of(INTEGER);
Out<Long> outE = Out.of(LONG);
Out<String> oufF = Out.of(VARCHAR);
Out<String> outG = Out.of(VARCHAR);
jdbcTemplate.execute(call("proname")
    .in("a", a)
    .in("b", b)
    .in("c", c)
    .in("z", z)
    .inOut("d", d, outD)
    .out("e", outE)
    .out("f", outF)
    .out("g", outG));

System.out.println("d=" + outD.get() + ", e=" + outE.get() + ", f=" + outF.get() + ", g=" + outG.get());
```

In case if you have a POJO for in/out parameters it can be even more laconic, e.g.

```java
@lombok.Data // generates getters, setters, toString
public class ProData {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private int z;
    private int d;
    private long e;
    private String f;
    private String g;
}
...
ProData data = ...;

jdbcTemplate.execute(call("proname")
    .in("a", data.getA())
    .in("b", data.getB())
    .in("c", data.getC())
    .in("z", data.getZ())
    .inOut("d", data.getD(), data::setD)
    .out("e", LONG, data::setE)
    .out("f", VARCHAR, data::setF)
    .out("g", VARCHAR, data::setG));

System.out.println("Data: " + data);
```

Please note, that for function the call should be not `call("proname")`, but `call("proname", VARCHAR)` (you did not declare the function result type). The call should look like

```java
String result = jdbcTemplate.execute(call("proname", VARCHAR)
    .in("a", data.getA())
    .in("b", data.getB())
    .in("c", data.getC())
    .in("z", data.getZ())
    .inOut("d", data.getD(), data::setD)
    .out("e", LONG, data::setE)
    .out("f", VARCHAR, data::setF)
    .out("g", VARCHAR, data::setG));
```